# Understanding concatMap recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am overall confused, and looking for a very detailed and explanatory answer, of how this code works:

```
let xs = [1] ++ concatMap (\x -> [x+1,x*10]) xs in xs
```

How does concatMap know what to map and concat over?

I understand more basic examples:

```
let x = [1] ++ x
```

Here it gets evaluated like `[1] ++ [1] ++ [1] ..`

But I don't seem to understand the first example with concatMap. It just doesn't make sense to me. I can work with recursion frequently without problems. However, that one piece of code is very confusing.

Comment: `concatMap` concatenates and maps over `xs` because that's what's passed to it. I'm unclear on what's confusing you here.

Comment: @TuttiFruttiJacuzzi It's the recursive definition of `xs`.

Comment: For the direct analogy to the one you understand, it gets evaluated like `[1] ++ concatMap (\x -> [x+1,x*10]) ([1] ++ concatMap (\x -> [x+1,x*10]) ([1] ++ concatMap (\x -> [x+1,x*10]) (...)))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try a much simpler example:

```
let xs = 1 : xs in xs
```

OK, so `xs` points to a `(:)` node. The head-pointer from here points to `1`, and the tail-pointer points to `xs` (i.e., back to itself). So this is either a circular list, or an infinite list. (Haskell regards the two as the same thing.) So far, so good.

Now, let's try a harder example:

```
let xs = 1 : map (+1) xs in xs
```

Do you know what this will do?

So `xs` points to a `(:)` node. The head-pointer points to 1. The tail-pointer points to the expression `map (+1) xs`, with `xs` pointing back to the top again.

If you try to "look at" the contents of this list, it will cause the `map` expression to start executing. The definition of `map` is

```
map f js =
  case js of
    k:ks -> (f k) : (map f ks)
    []   -> []
```

So `map` looks at `xs` to see if it's `[]` or `(:)`. As we know, it's `(:)`. So the first pattern applies.

What this means is that the entire `map (+1) xs` expression gets overwritten with `(:)`, with its head-pointer pointing to `(+1) 1` and its tail-pointer pointing to `map (+1) xs2` (with `xs2` denoting a pointer to the tail of `xs`).

At this point, inspecting `(+1) 1` turns it into `2`. So now we basically have

```
xs = 1 : 2 : map (+1) xs2
           ^           |
           |___________|
```

This cycle repeats as you examine the list. Critically, at every moment `map` is pointing to a node just before itself. If it ever caught up to itself, you would have a problem. But `map` only ever looks at nodes we've already calculated, so it's fine.

The net result, then, is `xs = 1 : 2 : 3 : 4 : ...`

If you can understand that, you ought to be able to understand your own more complicated example.

If you *want* to make your head hurt, try:

```
fibs = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

This is a standard Haskell incantation for spitting out the Fibonacci numbers in O(N) time (rather than O(N*N) as the more obvious recursion would give you).

Answer (score 1):

Think of *concatMap* as a simple composition of *concat* and *map* (*concat . map*).

In this particular case, you are initializing xs with 1. Once you start running your map, it will lift the lambda to operate on 1 (the first position in the list) and create a list containing two values, 2 and 10. Concat just extracts those two values from that list and puts them naked in xs, concatenating them with the existing 1. At this point, xs contains 1, 2 and 10 (*xs = [1,2,10]*).

Now, xs contains 1, 2 and 10 and map will repeat the process (of course, starting from the second position in the list), now operating on 2 and creating a list containing 3 and 20 and a second list containing 11 and 100 when operating on 10 (third position in the list). Concat will now extract those 4 values and append them to the contents of xs. Now xs contains 1, 2, 10, 3, 20, 11 and 100 (*xs = [1,2,10,3,20,11,100]*).

And you can rinse and repeat, this time map operating on the fourth position in the list (and every subsequent position), and concat doing its work to remove the new list containers and place the values directly into the top level list. As you can see, this process will generate that infinite list.

Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

First, what is `concat`? It concatenates lists, presented to it in a list:

```
concat [ [1], [2],    [3] ] = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
concat [ [1], [2,22], [3] ] = [ 1, 2, 22, 3 ]
```

and so forth. What does `map` do? It transforms each element in a list it is presented with:

```
map (1+)               [1, 2, 3] = [ 2, 3, 4 ]
map (:[])              [1, 2, 3] = [ [1], [2], [3] ]
map (\x-> [x+1, x*10]) [1, 2, 3] = [ [2,10], [3,20], [4,30] ]
```

But `concatMap f xs` is the same as `concat (map f xs)`:

```
concatMap (\x-> [x+1, x*10]) [1, 2, 3] 
 = concat (map (\x-> [x+1, x*10]) [1, 2, 3])
 = concat [ [2,10], [3,20], [4,30] ]
 = [ 2,10, 3,20, 4,30 ]
```

But, it doesn't need to see the input list through to its end, in order to proceed, producing its elements one by one. This is because of Haskell's laziness. Simply,

```
   concat [ [2,10], [3,20], [4,30] ]
 = [ 2,10, 3,20, 4,30 ]
 = [ 2,10] ++ concat [ [3,20], [4,30] ]
```

This means that actually,

```
concat xs == foldr (++) [] xs
-- concat [a,b,...,n] = a ++ (b ++ (... ++ (n++[])...))
```

and

```
concatMap f xs == foldr ((++).f) [] xs
-- concatMap f [a,b,...,n] = f a ++ (f b ++ (... ++ (f n++[])...))
```

so it does work incrementally. For your example,

```
let xs = [1] ++ concatMap (\x -> [x+1,x*10]) xs in xs
== let xs = [1] ++ foldr ((++).(\x -> [x+1,x*10])) [] xs in xs
== let xs = [1] ++ foldr (\x -> ([x+1,x*10] ++)) [] xs in xs
== let xs = [1] ++ foldr (\x r -> x+1 : x*10 : r) [] xs in xs
```

Which simply means: `xs` is a list, which contains `1`, and then `x+1` and `x*10` for each element `x` in *`xs`* - *from the start again*. We could write this down also as

```
xs = 1 : [y | x <- xs, y <- [x+1, x*10]]
```

So for 1, *2* and *10* will be "appended" *at list's end*, then for 2, *3* and *20* will be produced, for 10 - *11* and *100*, and so on:

```
xs =   1    a    b    c    d    e    f    g    h ....
    [2,10]=[a,b]
   =   1    2   10    c    d    e    f    g    h ....
          [3,20]=[c,d]
   =   1    2   10    3   20    e    f    g    h ....
               [11,100]=[e,f]
       ....
```

Of course this won't be evaluated on its own; the definition is "dormant" until used, e.g. to print the first 6 elements of `xs`:

> Prelude> let xs = 1 : [y | x <- xs, y <- [x+1, x*10]] 
>   Prelude> take 6 xs 
>   [1,2,10,3,20,11]

As we can see, what's really been defined here is not an infinite list - there are no infinite things after all - but a process of calculating as much of its elements as might be needed.

Yet another way of writing this definition is

```
xs = 1 : next xs
         where
         next (x:xs) = x+1 : x*10 : next xs
```

where the computation's structure is seen yet clearer: `next` "looks back" into `xs` as it is being defined, first 1 notch back; then 2; then 3; etc. (because it produces two new list elements for each one it consumes; this definition is thus *productive*). This is characteristic of a *"corecursive"* definition. Its calculation proceeds as

```
take 6 xs
 = take 6 xs where xs=1:next xs                   -- next looks 1 element back
 = 1:take 5 xs1 where xs=1:xs1; xs1=next xs
 = 1:take 5 xs1 where xs1=2:10:next xs1                -- 2 elements back
 = 1:2:take 4 xs2 where xs1=2:xs2; xs2=10:next xs1
 = 1:2:10:take 3 xs3 where xs1=2:xs2; xs2=10:xs3; xs3=next xs1
 = 1:2:10:take 3 xs3 where xs2=10:xs3; xs3=3:20:next xs2       -- 3 elements 
 = 1:2:10:3:take 2 xs4 where xs2=10:xs3; xs3=3:xs4; xs4=20:next xs2
 = 1:2:10:3:20:take 1 xs5 where xs2=10:xs3; xs3=3:xs4; xs4=20:xs5; xs5=next xs2
 = 1:2:10:3:20:take 1 xs5 where xs3=3:xs4; xs4=20:xs5; xs5=11:100:next xs3     -- 4 
 ....
```